# A software to test websites (cross-browsing and multi-devices)

Tags: windows, osx, web-development

As I'm working on my website (HTML5/CSS3), I need a software (free or not) to test my website on multiple browsers and resolutions.
I'm not searching for online services, like browserstacks or any others cause I'm not always connected to internet. 
I forgot to mention, that I'm working on OSX(main workstation) but I also own a computer with W8 running on it so, I'm taking any recommandations.
Thanks for all.

EDIT : My website is set on local (Mamp), and I'm trying to make sure it's cross-browser and responsive/adaptative as well. I used to use the "toggle device mode" from chrome but it's not really worth of trust, it didn't show me the same thing since I'm using vh/vw units. I think the mobile phone mode didn't really emulate a phone, but just put the website in a smaller div and keeped the screen size.

Comment: Could you clarify the kinds of test you expect to run? You mention multiple resolutions as an issue. There will be limits on what can be automated - software cannot tell you if a page looks visually appealing, but it could tell you if an element is displayed at all, and perhaps where. You don't mention any server-side or client-side scripting language, so I assume the tests of behaviour would be limited to verifying images and hyperlinks - is that correct? Testing software will need to be scripted, what scripting languages can you consider?

Comment: ...(continued) or are you looking for software without scripting that you can configure to check certain things (e.g. that all the hyperlinks work)?

Comment: Thanks for the attention, I edited to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will, of course, have to install those multiple browsers on your PC.

After that, you can't beat [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

```
Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to  
you. 

Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly  
not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) 
also be automated as well.

Selenium has the support of some of the largest browser vendors who have taken   
(or are taking) steps to make Selenium a native part of their browser.  
 It is also the core technology in countless other browser automation tools,   
 APIs and frameworks.
```

When I was looking for the same thing as you, I couldn't find anything better.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out besides I already have those browsers :)

Comment: Totally lost here, I'll see some tutorials but I'm not sure if it's what I need there. (I have some difficulties to understand what use, I'll need it for ? What use did you make of it ?)

Comment: @Yoshino: Typically Selenium is used to automate testing of more complex web applications, but it could be scripted (in a variety of languages) to test many aspects of any web site. My company uses it for "smoke tests" where we show that various user scenarios work on the site before we release. Selenium can be used for many things, so it can also be complex to set up.

Comment: there is an firefox addon "selenium ide". This is kind of gui to create and run tests.